# iOS app runtime crash only in iOS 6 release but runs fine with iOS 6 debug and iOS 7 debug and release

Tags: ios

The error log is:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/A40285D5-6B3E-4DE1-8B75-A1D5841A0/*.app/*
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>         dyld: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
>   Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/A40285D5-6B3E-4DE1-8B75-A1D5841A0/*.app/*
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

My app works fine in iOS 6 debug and iOS 7 debug and release, but crashes in iOS 6 release.

The detail is that I import  in my .mm file, and it crashes when call the `cos()` function.

I just worked on this question for the whole day, really crazy. Please help me if someone can work it out. Thank you very much,

Comment: The problem has been solved by me.To solve the problem I just set the development target of my workspace,not only the main workspace but also my imported workspace.